# Entity relationship between NSManagedObjects issue

Tags: ios, exception, core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject

I'm running into a CoreData problem related to one-to-many relationships.

Entity 1 - `Authors` has a one-to-many relationship with Entity 2 - `Books`. I think `Books` has a one-to-one relationship with `Authors`.

Since there are multiple books per author in the author object I have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *book;
```

The corresponding property in the book object is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Authors *author;
```

When the app downloads books from the server through an API, after saving the book, I am trying to also save the author and associate the book with the author with the following code:

```
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Books" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

 NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
record setValue:bookname forKey:@"bookname"];

if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    Authors *newAuthor = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Authors" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                        newAuthor.aid = authorid;                      
                        newAuthor.book = record;
}
```

This code has worked for me for one to one relationships, but in this case, is throwing following exception error:

> ```
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for
>  to-many relationship: property = "book"; desired type = NSSet; given 
>  type = Books;
> ```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Update:

I also tried switching it around to read:

```
record.author = newAuthor;
```

But this gives error

> "property 'author' not found on object of type NSManagedObject"

although there is such a property defined in the `Books` object (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `book` property is a set, CoreData should have created an `Authors` method such as `addBookObject:`.  When you created your custom entity classes, there should be a file with a name similar to "Authors+CoreDataProperties.h".  Look in there for defined methods.

Your second option should also work if you use `Books` instead of `NSManagedObject`.
i.e.:

```
Books *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Sorry to be dense but I have been hitting my head on this for a while... Books *record = ????

Comment: also if core data creates the method is this under the hood or should I be doing something?

Comment: I attempted to fix the answer.  Let me know how we're doing.  :)

Answer (score 0):

U can generate `NSManagedObject` subclass, after just create few objects, set relations and save context once, someting like:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
Book *newBook = [[Book alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.context];
newBook.bookName = @"My new book";

NSEntityDescription *entity2 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Record" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
Record *newRecord = [[Record alloc] initWithEntity:entity2 insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.context];
newRecord.name = @"New record";

newBook.record = newRecord;
[newRecord addBook:[NSSet setWithObject:newBook]];

[self.context save:nil];
```

This is sample for db like below:

[image]

To autogenerate classes - select Entities in *.xcdatamodel file and press File->New->File select `CoreData` section and NSManaged Object subclass, go by wizard steps.

You will get something like

[image]

And even more:

[image]

Good tutorial u can also found [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-core-data-stack--cms-20926)